# evaluating else if after an if condition is true

Tags: c#, if-statement

Consider this snippet:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.MaxLength > 0)
    {
        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToBoolean(Math.Sqrt(textBox1.MaxLength)).ToString();
    }
    else if (textBox1.MaxLength < 32768)
    {
        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToBoolean(Math.Sqrt(textBox1.MaxLength)).ToString();
    }                
}
```

Why is it not evaluating the second condition (the lesser than condition)? It's also true, isn't it?

If I have to make the second one to work in the same condition, what minor change must be made?

Comment: what is the value of textbox1.MaxLength?

Comment: If you can afford the Lexus, buy it. Else, if you can afford the Honda, buy that. In this situation, would you expect to buy both the Lexus and the Honda?

Comment: @Sebastian Piu, textbox1.MaxLength =32767

Comment: If that is the default value of the property ( it likely is ) why are you checking to see if its greater then that value?

Comment: @Marie Curie then you already have your answer

Comment: i told it is not about logic, sebastian

Comment: I gave a +1 to all who gave me an answer, Thanks for helping out girls and boys :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`else if` is only checked if the first condition isn't satisfied.

If you want both of them to be true, you should do

```
if(textBox1.MaxLength > 0 && textBox1.MaxLength < 32768)
{
   // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anna Lear. Yesterday, on another question some one told me about the use of ++ and -- operator, is && is same as that is my only doubt?

Comment: && is a Boolean AND statement || is a Boolean OR statement. & and | are Bit AND and OR statements.

Comment: @Marie Curie: No. && is an AND statement, ++ is an increase operation, -- is a decrease operation and is designed to work on numbers.

Answer (score 8):

The second condition isn't being checked because an `else` statement will only be evaluated when the preceding conditions are evaluated to be `false`. There are several ways to fix this, some of which are shown in other answers. One such way is to use a single `if` statement, which combines both conditions:

```
if (textBox1.MaxLength > 0 && textBox1.MaxLength < 32768)
{
    textBox2.Text = Convert.ToBoolean(Math.Sqrt(textBox1.MaxLength)).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the second if statement to run even if the first was true?
Get rid of the else

Comment: This will cause the `textBox2.Text` property to get set though the value is not lesser than 32768. Merging both conditions into only one interval condition is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using else if instead of another if.

Answer (score 1):

It will only reach the second part if the first one is false. If you want to check against both you should do this:

```
 if (textBox1.MaxLength > 0 && textBox1.MaxLength < 32768)
```

You can look at && like this:

```
if (A && B) {
    //do something
}
```

is the same as

```
if (A) { 
    if (B) { 
        //do something 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your answer looks like anna, I dont know who answered first. Anyway thanks

Comment: Doesn't really matter. I think everyone answered at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you want both if-then statements to execute, you have to remove the "else". Otherwise it will only execute the firt if (if it's true).

Answer (score 1):

You'll never reach the second `if`, because **any** number larger than 0 will satisfy the first `if` before the second, more restrictive condition. To put it in simpler terms, the first `if` will match all numbers n where `n > 0`, whereas the second `if` matches numbers `32768 > n > 0`.

Comment: What if 0? It's not >0 and it is <32768 :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your "else if" statement is not happening is because

```
if (textBox1.MaxLength > 0)
```

is always true, since MaxLength obviously will always be greater then 0, unless it was changed to be 0.

I would like to add that

```
textBox1.MaxLength < 32768
```

Likely also will always be true.

Additionally

> When this property is set to 0, the
>   maximum length of the text that can be
>   entered in the control is limited only
>   by available memory.

Answer (score 1):

Think of `else if` as actually being written this way:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //textBox2.Text += Convert.ToString (textBox1.Text + "garment");
    if (textBox1.MaxLength > 0)
    {
        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToBoolean(Math.Sqrt(textBox1.MaxLength)).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        if (textBox1.MaxLength < 32768)
        {
            textBox2.Text = Convert.ToBoolean(Math.Sqrt(textBox1.MaxLength)).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

It's the same thing. Note that the second `if` sstatement is only executed when the first is false.

Comment: Your "else" part is a bit verbose, you should think of merging your "else" statement into an "else if"

Comment: @Gendolkari: I wish it was... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this, if I would like to say "if MaxLength is between 0 and 32768":

```
if (0 < textBox1.MaxLength && textBox1.MaxLength < 32768)
    textBox2.Text = Convert.ToBoolean(Math.Sqrt(textBox1.MaxLength)).ToString();
```

Since you're doing the same in this interval, it is more appropriate to make both in the same condition statement.