# Else if Logic question when A == true && B == true

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, logic

If the conditions A and B are true at the same time, will the program execute the else if condition in the following code :

> if(A && B){
> TODO CODE 1;}
>
> else if(A || B){
>
> TODO CODE 2;}

I wonder if TODO CODE 2 will be executed.

In other words : does the "if" structure prevails or the logic prevails ?

Because (A || B ) is true when (A == true && B == true) right ?

Many Thanks,

Guillaume

I ran a program and fell in an infinite loop due to this problem.

I could check the answer by debugging with a simple test but I prefer an explanation from someone with experience in logic.

---

It is a JAVA 19 program. The code is the following :

```
if(this.zombie && ennemi.zombie) { 
    System.out.println("Combat de zombies ! "); 
    int rnd = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*2); 
    if(rnd == 0 ){ 
        this.state = State.Mort; 
    }else 
        ennemi.state = State.Mort ; 
}else if(this.zombie || ennemi.zombie){ 
    this.zombie = true; 
    this.state = State.Zombie; 
    ennemi.zombie = true; 
    ennemi.state = State.Zombie; 
}
```

Comment: What language was that program in and can you post the code? In any sensible language, though, the `elseif` branch should _not_ be evaluated if the first `if` condition already evaluated to `true`. Btw, that is less of an issue with logic but language design / control flow.

Comment: But only regarding the logic part of that question: If A&&B is true (which means A is true and B is true) then it can be inferred that A||B (= inclusive OR) is also true.

Comment: It is a JAVA 19 program.
The code is the following :
`code`
 if(this.zombie && ennemi.zombie) {
            System.out.println("Combat de zombies ! ");
            int rnd = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
            if(rnd == 0 ){
                this.state = State.Mort;
            }else ennemi.state = State.Mort ;

        }else if(this.zombie || ennemi.zombie){

            this.zombie = true;
            this.state = State.Zombie;
            ennemi.zombie = true;
            ennemi.state = State.Zombie;
        }`code`

Comment: It's more readable if you [edit] the question and add the code as code-formatted text there. Thank you! ( Did it myself ... :D )

Comment: I don't see how this code would cause an infinite loop. There is no loop and no recursion. I also don't see how both branches could be evaluated. It _should_ work as expected (without having tried, admittedly).

Comment: This code won't cause infinite loop indeed.

But it will cause the program not to terminate due to the program's general logic (I could link you the program if interested but that is not the question).

Comment: Anyway, I guess you answered my question so thank you for that !

Comment: If you want to try a different approach just for fun/learning/experiment: You can take an `int test = 0;` And then do `test += this.zombie? 1 : 0; test += ennemie.zombie? 1 : 0;` and then switch/case on `test` for cases 2,1 and 0. If that results in the same behavior, then it wasn't caused by the if/elseif.

Comment: I think I see what you meant, will try that !

Answer (score 0):

When the statement for the IF block is true, Else (and Else If) is not entered or evaluated. In your example above, when A and B are both True, the code inside the IF block will be executed, and then the program will skip the rest of the IF...Else and move onto the next line of code.

Yes. The "If structure" prevails.

It looks like a similar question to yours has been answered a lot on a post from a while back: [evaluating else if after an if condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491834/evaluating-else-if-after-an-if-condition-is-true)

Comment: Mind: In the linked question, OP actually asks for the complete opposite. There, OP _wanted_ both evaluated. So answers will probably explain the behavior but the presented solutions will cause the opposite behavior to what Gui Gui requires.

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well Nick. It confirms what Fildor says, in a different manner. Sorry for double post, but each case is different and sometimes we don't find what we are looking for in other people questions. Hope you can understand that ;)

Comment: @Fildor thanks for clarifying that! I didn't mean to imply that this was duplicate, only that the many answers on the previous post could help, since they delve into the logic and theory of If...Else.  Gui Gui, all is good, I hope it was at least helpful.